# Use decorator with same name as an instance method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have the following snippet:

```
from decorators import before_save

class User(Model):
    def before_save(self):
        pass

    @before_save
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

It seems that when I try to decorate `meth`, it "uses" the instance method `before_save`, not the imported decorator. How can I still declare an instance method with the same name as a decorator and still be able to properly use both of them?

Shouldn't the decorator work as expected? How is it possible to refer to the `before_save` instance method just as `before_save`, without any reference to its class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following

```
import decorators
# omitted

@decorators.before_save
def meth(self):
    pass
```

I wanted to use a one-liner but run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28995713/4354477).

Comment: I understand. But how come the code gets in some scope that allows the use of `before_save` to reference the newly defined instance method?

Comment: @AndreiHorak, sorry, I don't quite understand, could you rephrase your comment, please?

Comment: The defined instance method `before_save` shouldn't be called prepended with a reference to its class? This way the decorator would work as expected. Don't know how else I could ask better...:)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the import name:

```
from decorators import before_save as before_save_decorator

class User(Model):
    def before_save(self):
        pass

    @before_save_decorator
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

That should let you use both.

Comment: ForceBru's solution is better if you need to change more than one import name, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could define `before_save` method after:

```
from decorators import before_save

class User(Model):

    @before_save
    def meth(self):
        pass

    def before_save(self):
        pass
```

But this is not the best solution, because it's not obvious what's going on here, and you can forget about later.