# Unexpected SyntaxError with decorators

Tags: python

Here the goal is to call a *global* function as a decorator.

```
#coding: utf-8
def Test(method_to_decorate):
    print 'Decorator'
    def wrapper(self):
        return method_to_decorate(self)
    return wrapper


class Smth(object):
    def Test(self):
        print 'NOT a decorator!'

    a=globals()['Test']

    #@globals()['Test'] --> SyntaxError
    @a # works fine
    def Fun(self):
        print "Smth.Fun()"

l = Smth()
l.Fun()
```

Using the uncommented approach works fine while `@globals()['Test']` gives `SyntaxError`. **Why?** I'm *quite sure* `Test` *exists* in `globals()`.

The thing after `@` must be a function accepting another function as one of its arguments, am I right? `globals()['Test']` is such a function, isn't it? Then, in my opinion, `@globals()['Test']` must be correct (logically correct).

**Edit**

This works as expected:

```
def Ex(*args):
    print 'Ex({})'.format(args) 
globals()['Ex']('hello') # just calling a function
```

While a decorator is used, a function is called. We can call functions as above but can't use a decorator like this. **Maybe this is some sort of a Python bug or logic misorganisation?**

Comment: It's a syntax error, not a runtime error. Your syntax is not correct - that's not how you use decorators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a SyntaxError because Python's grammar explicitly does not allow that; the tokens on the right of `@` are not an expression. [1](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) Instead, valid syntax is:

```
decorator: '@' dotted_name [ '(' [arglist] ')' ] NEWLINE
```

(A phrase enclosed in square brackets (`[ ]`) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional).) [2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/introduction.html#notation)

Following from the above, you can get this to work by converting `globals()['Test']` to a dotted name. The following examples should work:

```
g = globals()
@g.get('Test')
def Fun(self):
    pass

x = globals()['Test']
@x
def Fun(self):
  pass
```

Or, as you noticed, you can just skip the syntactic sugar and decorate manually, which is probably the least bad option.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I had tested with a dictionary `d`, rather than `globals()`. Edited my answer to fix the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Python parser isn't designed to recognize an index access as part of decorator syntax. Consider writing a separate function that accesses `globals()` instead.