# Python decorator with same name as an instance method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a very similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994359/use-decorator-with-same-name-as-an-instance-method) except I would like to name my function `property`

so for example Id like to do something like:

```
class ThingWithProperties(object):

    def property(self, a):
        print("in property", a)

    @property
    def test(self):
        print("in test")

t = Testing()
t.property(1)
t.test()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ThingWithProperties(object):
  File "test.py", line 10, in ThingWithProperties
    @property
TypeError: property() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

Could someone please explain why this is happening? As well as how to work around it (**without renaming my instance method**)?

Comment: Try defining your property method after all the usage of the decorator are done in the scope of the definition of that class.  I.e. define `test` before `property`.

Comment: You really should rename your instance method.

Comment: I am going to rename it. I just wanted to know why it was being shadowed and the other question got nothing but answers saying "just rename it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because by defining a method called `property`, you are shadowing the builtin `property` within the scope of the class declaration. Hence when you write `@property`, your method is called to decorate `test` as opposed to the builtin `property`.

You could use the `__builtin__` module to explicitly use the builtin `property`:

```
class ThingWithProperties(object):

    def property(self, a):
        print("in property", a)

    @__builtin__.property
    def test(self):
        print("in test")
```

Though I personally always avoid shadowing builtins, even if they are only shadowed in a limited scope, as is the case here.

---

To be a little more clear about the "shadowing" going on, try running this in your interpreter:

```
foo = 42
print(foo)

class Test:
    foo = 73
    print(foo)

print(foo)
```

There are two points to make here: First, some might be surprised that we can `print` things in a class definition. The point is that a class definition is a code block like any other, and you can write `for`-loops and `print` all you'd like, and whatever variables or functions you create are gathered together into a class dictionary when it comes time to actually create the class.

The second point is that the class definition creates a new scope, and the value of `foo` inside the scope is different than outside. That is, the above prints `42`, then `73`, then `42` again.

Comment: I also "always avoid shadowing builtins, even if they are only shadowed in a limited scope, as is the case here."